# UPDATE multiple rows/columns with single query (perfomamce)

Tags: php, mysql

Two simple scenarios:

```
$group_sql  = $db->prepare("UPDATE `groups` SET `group`=? WHERE `group_id`=?;");

foreach($_POST['groups'] as $id => $group)
{
    $group_sql->execute(array($group, $id));
}
```

And multi-update:

```
$query      = array();

foreach($_POST['groups'] as $id => $group)
{
    $query[]    = "WHEN {$id} THEN {$db->quote($group)}";
}

$query      = "
UPDATE `groups`
SET `group` = CASE `group_id`
    " . implode("\r\n", $query) . "
END
WHERE `group_id` IN (" . implode(',', array_keys($_POST['groups'])) . ");
";
```

Which will eventually generate:

```
UPDATE `groups`
SET `group` = CASE `group_id`
    WHEN 3054 THEN 'moteris savo vaikams'
    WHEN 3055 THEN 'bičių šeimoje'
END
WHERE `group_id` IN (3054,3055)
```

Which one is better to use?

**UPDATE**

Since I noticed that people are not familiar with such method, I've decided to expand the example to use multiple column/row update.

```
UPDATE `groups`
    SET `group` = CASE `group_id`
        WHEN 3054 THEN 'moteris savo vaikams'
        WHEN 3055 THEN 'bičių šeimoje'
    END,
    SET `description` = CASE `group_id`
        WHEN 3054 THEN 'foo'
        WHEN 3055 THEN 'bar'
    END
    WHERE `group_id` IN (3054,3055)
```

Comment: Before anyone commented about security, this example does not follow any variable sanitizing, as the question is not about that.

Comment: +1 I´ve never seen or used the second one, but I was wondering about the same thing a while back using your first scenario or a third scenario, using a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on your table and index structure. If `group_id` is index so that it can look it up directly, without scanning an index or a table it should yield similar performance.

If it isn't indexed the last form should be able to handle with one index/table scan instead of two, which will get better performance.

Interesting idea to handle multiupdates that way, haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

The query plans will, for all intents and purposes, be the same if you've an index on group_id: you'll do an index lookup per ID anyway. If not, you'll get a single table scan, instead of one per ID.

There will be a slight performance advantage to the multi-query, in the sense that you'll avoid round trips to the database. Whether this is worth the hassle of not using an ORM is a different story altogether.